# How can I listen to events in Gutenberg block?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I want to do something when my block gets deleted, added or re-ordered. How can I accomplish this? Is there a workaround of some sort?

Answer (score 3):

Aside from @Luis Martins answer, another simpler approach is possible. Use useEffect hook in a child block, like so:

```
useEffect(() => {
  // here goes block creation code
  return () => {
    // here goes code when block is deleted
  }
, []}
```

Make sure you read about [useEffect hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html), and my example will be clearer. For sorting, I am not sure what happens internally, perhaps you have to use useSelect hook on parent to catch block position. Parent block has innerBlocks property, where each block is memeber of that array.

Comment: Brilliant way to check when deleted!

Answer (score 1):

WordPress documentation can be seriously lacking in some areas, so you'll need to do some digging to find some answers that are not always the clearest there.

A quick dirty example of how to "listen" to updates from a parent block could be:

```
const { attributes, clientId, isSelected, className, setAttributes } = props;

  const parentClientId = select('core/block-editor').getBlockHierarchyRootClientId(clientId);

  const { data } = useSelect((select) => {
    if (parentClientId) {
      return {
        data: select('core/block-editor').getBlockAttributes(parentClientId),
      };
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  });
```

Here `data` would hold the attributes from the parent block. There are probably cleaner ways to go about this, but hopefully this will point you in the right direction.